# Annotation MapKit Automation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, mapkit, core-location

I have my app running with 2 annotations for now.

They are hardcoded in with latitude and longitude.

How do I make it so that I let the user add the annotations and drop a pin where they wish and for my app to recognize this and save where they drop it? Any ideas or links please.

I believe that this is accomplishable by having a btn that when pressed creates a new instance of the annotation pin with draggable properties listed as

MyPin.draggable = YES;

My question is: how do I code the class so that the new instance can be created when needed.. and as many as are needed. (5, 8, 29 etc.)

hope this makes sense, if not, then I am basically looking to create something similar to the drop pin feature in google maps on iphones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an example
[Link](https://freshmob.com.au/mapkit-tap-and-hold-to-drop-a-pin-on-the-map/)

It uses a gesture recognizer. The only problem is that it does not retrieve the address.

Comment: I am not worried about it retrieving the address just as long as it can plot the point on the map and save it. Had a look at the link - his code is rather vague as in where you would place it and how you'd deal with it in your program.. any ideas?

Comment: The best way is not to create a class but have an NSMtableArray with the Annotations and store them within the function you use from to call.